# how can deal with float *array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have array declared in something like this

**first way**

```
int size=256*10;
float *array=(float*)malloc(size * sizeof(float));
for(int i=0;i<2398;i++)
     data[i]=data[i]*900;
```

When I used this why in declaration my code run with out errors but

when  I use the array as constant values like this :

**2nd way**

```
float array[]={120.0, 160.0, 255.0, 216.0, 255.0, 224.0, 0.0, 16.0, 
74.0, 70.0, 73.0, 70.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
```

I didn't get what was required from the code even if I took the array output in the first way and defined it as in 2nd way?!!
I thought defining an array in the 2nd way is correct and equivalent to the first definition?!
What is the correct way to declare an array that equivalent to the first way?

Comment: The correct way is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] for that error. `double array[]={120.0, 160.0, 255.0, 216.0, 255.0, 224.0, 0.0, 16.0, 74.0, 70.0, 73.0, 70.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};` should work.

Comment: OMG! you have 2560 constant values?

Comment: In `c++` you should avoid  `malloc` unless you need to do so to interface with `c`

Comment: *"What is the correct way to declare an array"* -- for starters, the line with the error does not declare an array; your array is declared on the line that starts with `float`. Then there is the issue that you seem to have two different initializations in mind -- provide a list of values and dynamic allocation. Do you need both? Why do you want to use dynamic allocation here (and why `malloc()` instead of `new` or `make_unique`)?

Comment: yes I have, but I want the array be float

Comment: Then declare it as a float and get rid of the malloc part: [https://ideone.com/TZ8Ckx](https://ideone.com/TZ8Ckx)

Comment: I didn't get a result, I didn't know why when I use the first way the code works correctly but when I use the second way the array is not read !!

Comment: Perhaps the problem isn't where you think it is. This is why showing a minimal reproducible example is important. If your problem is perhaps in code we can't see then we can't help.

Comment: What @TheUndeadFish says is correct and important. One reason why it is important to provide a small but complete example that exhibits the error is that often enough the error is gone in the small program. Then you can add the complexity step by step until it resurfaces, and find the reason. I think the majority of beginner questions could be answered by the people asking if they did their homework.

Comment: Detail: With `float *array`,  `array` in not an _array_.  It is a _pointer_.  Although they seem similar, they are not.

Comment: See also [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You had a problem with your array, and immediately assumed that your declaration was in error and asked about that. More beneficial for you would have been to focus on your original problem. Describe the symptoms. Provide a [mre] demonstrating the symptoms. After presenting the problem, you can present your failed attempt at a solution. This leaves opens the possibility of fixing your solution, but also invites better solutions and explanations of what the problem really is.

Answer (score 2):

Both ways create valid arrays, and you can use them pretty much exchangably if you pay attention to object life time. The differences are:

- `malloc` dynamically allocates memory which exists until the program explicitly calls `free()` on the address returned by malloc. One of the typical use cases is to allocate and initialize some storage in a function and *let the function return the address.* That's fine: The life time of objects in dynamically allocated memory (new, malloc) is independent of scope (e.g., a function).

  By contrast, an array defined the second way exists until the variable goes out of scope. If it is a global variable it will exist until the program ends. If it is defined in a function it will only exist until the program returns from the function, or ends. That may be your problem here. Returning the address of a function-local object and using it outside that function is a not uncommon error. Newer compilers with sufficiently high warning levels should warn when they see such a mistake.
- The second array is an object with the number of elements indicated by the initializers, exactly. You can call `sizeof(array)` and get a large number, for example 60. The first "array", by contrast, is not an array at all: It is a *pointer to the first element of an array.* Calling sizeof() on that pointer returns the size of that pointer, typically 4 or 8, no matter how much memory is allocated at the location the pointer points to. There is no built-in way to keep track of the size of the allocated memory — the programmer must store it somewhere. Typically, larger programs have a constant or a define somewhere in a header shared by "translation units" (source files) so that parts of the program that use the allocated memory don't overshoot its limits, and the part allocating it knows how much is needed.
- Standard C++ doesn't have variable length arrays: Array sizes must be known at compile time. That's obviously not always possible. For example, most image formats contain the image size in the first few bytes of the file. A program reading such an image would read a few bytes into an information structure and then dynamically allocate the needed memory for the actual pixels. If you want to use compile-time sized arrays you can, of course, simply define one that's big enough for large pictures and only use part of it for smaller ones. But you'll end up with array sizes that normally waste space because they are much too large for the average picture — but will probably *still* not fit the largest picture they may encounter! It is much better to use a data structure whose size can be determined or changed at run time, like a `std::vector`, or arrays created with `new()` or, if you must, `malloc()`.

Remarks:

1. You don't use the entire allocated memory which is a bit strange: You allocate 2560 floats but assign values only to 2398.
2. The assignment `data[i]=data[i]*900;` reads from the uninitialized element `data[i]` before assigning to it. Reading uninitialized memory is *verboten* and *kaput* ("undefined behavior"), and the program is faulty. In practice you'll probably simply have funny float values, but still. Don't do it.

If you have an array you want to initialize with a few dozen values known at compile time I'd strongly prefer a true array. If it needs to live longer than the function you can make it static  and let the function return a pointer to it.

Only if you need a lot of memory (2500 floats qualifies) or must create an array whose size is unknown at compile time, or must create an unknown number of arrays, consider creating them dynamically.

As others have remarked in comments, real-world code would use a vector or a smart pointer and/or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Explicit dynamic allocation has pretty much become a domain of beginner homework (I'm not condescending: It has its place there) or projects stuck with old compilers (don't ask).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good point -- correct terminology is half the explanation...